# How to handle the stock table quantity after sale

Tags: stock

I have a problem. I am not understanding that how to deduct the quantity from stock after sale and we have multiple entries of same stock
like:

| id | Medicine | Company | quantity | item price | is deleted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Panadol | Abbott | 200 | 10.00 | 0 |
| 2 | Panadol | Abbott | 100 | 11.00 | 0 |
| 3 | Panadol | Abbott | 100 | 12.00 | 0 |

now how to deduct the quantity of stock and  one thing is more that this product/Medicine has separate manufacturing and expiry date
please tell me how to handle it.
I was thinking that to make separate table for tracking  the remaining stock quantity.
or runtime management to calculate all the sale quantity minus(-) sum of all quantities entered to get
the current stock quantity.
Please guide me.